# Python OpenCV Images to Video Not all images are displayed in frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a video out of a list of images using opencv, where I display each picture for 5 seconds. But the code produces a video which shows only 1 image with a duration of 5 seconds (out of 5 images). What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

video_name = 'test/video.avi'

images = ['db\\images\\generic\\COCO_val2017\\000000532901.jpg', 'db\\images\\generic\\COCO_val2017\\000000415990.jpg', 'db\\images\\generic\COCO_val2017\\000000402615.jpg', 'db\\images\\generic\\COCO_val2017\\000000363188.jpg', 'db\\images\\generic\\COCO_val2017\\000000250901.jpg']
frame = cv2.imread(images[0])
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width, height))

for image in images:
    for _ in range(5):
        video.write(cv2.imread(image))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

The images are located at a shared location in the network, but even locally the issue exists.

If I copy about 30~ images, only about ~4 of them will be present at the video.

What is the issue?

Comment: Check the arguments of `cv2.VideoWriter`. What does `, 0, 1,` means?

Comment: 0 is the codec, 1 is the fps (so should be 1 frame per second)

Comment: `fourcc=0` is reserved for saving image sequence. Try `video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 1, (width, height))`.

Comment: In my PC your code is working, even with `fourcc=0`. The video codec is `I420` (raw video codec). It is most likely that the resolution of `000000415990.jpg` is different from `000000532901.jpg`. Try: `video.write(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image), (width, height)))`

Comment: @Rotem Working!! So indeed the issue was with the images having different resolution. Toda raba!!